# Где тут деление на ноль и как его обойти?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Есть некая база

```
new ItemModel("Water", 0, 1, 0),
new ItemModel("Ballast", 0, 1, 0),
new ItemModel("Oil", 0, 1, 0),
```

и соответственно числам есть некие формулы

```
private int _weight;
public int Weight
{
    get => _weight;
    set
    {
        _weight = value;
        //_volume = value / _sg;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}

private int _sg;
public int Sg
{
    get => _sg;
    set
    {
        _sg = value;
        Volume = _weight / value;
        Weight = value * _volume;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}



private int _volume;
public int Volume
{
    get => _volume;
    set
    {
        _volume = value;
        _weight = value * _sg;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

меня интересует данный момент

```
_volume = value / _sg;
```

так как по сути формула - 0=0/1
но компилятор выдаёт мне запрет деления на ноль

```
class ItemModel
{
    public ItemModel(string name, int weight, int sg, int volume)
    {
        Name = name;
        Weight = weight;
        Sg = sg;
        Volume = volume;

    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int Sg { get; set; }
    public int Volume { get; set; }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ItemModel("Water", 0, 1, 0)
```

Если инициализация свойств идет в таком порядке: Weight, Sg, Volume, то при инициализации Weight должен быть инициализирован Sg  :

```
private int _weight;
public int Weight
{
    get => _weight;
    set
    {
        _weight = value;
        //_volume = value / _sg; здесь _sg еще не инициализирован и равен 0.
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

Наилучшим решением будет, присваивать параметры не через сеттер, а сразу полям:

```
_weight = argWeght;
_sg = argSg;
_volume = argValue;
```

дальше:

```
private int _weight;
public int Weight
{
    get { return _weight; } 
    set
    {
        _weight = value;  
        _volume = value / _sg;
        //т.к. все свойства зависят друг от друга, то необходимо оповестить их об изменении           
        RaisePropertyChanged("Weight");
        RaisePropertyChanged("Value");
        RaisePropertyChanged("Sg");
    }
}

public ItemModel(string name, int weight, int sg, int volume)
{
   _name = name;
   _weight = weght;
   _sg = sg;
   _volume = volume;
}
```

и с остальными свойствами проделать такие же манипуляции

Comment: А как можно инициализировать _sg раньше?

Comment: @LeeShane взять и инициализировать раньше?

Comment: @Gardes прошу прощения, но я ещё учусь. А где надо присваивать значения?

Comment: @LeeShane, в конструкторе ItemModel

Comment: @Gardes добавил итем модел, можете сказать где именно?

Comment: @LeeShane, вы пишете: "Есть некая база: new ItemModel("Water", 0, 1, 0)", вы получается вызываете конструктор ItemModel, в нем и надо присваивать значения

Comment: @Gardes я добавил в вопрос `class ItemModel`. Вы могли бы "ткнуть пальцем" где надо это вписать?

Comment: @LeeShane, обновил ответ, проверяйте